# How do I verify my receiver for paypal adaptive payments

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have what seems to be an uncommon situation. I need to accept payments on my website and send them to various merchants that do their business though my app.

So the payment flow is:

Payer -> My App -> My Customer

This flow seems to be exactly facilitated by paypal's adaptive payments api and while I have pored over all their integration guides, there doesn't seem to be any documentation for even simple email to account verification.

My question is, how can I verify that an email belongs to a verified paypal business account, or perform some other hand shake verification? Is there a way to do that, or even a good workaround? Thanks!

Comment: From what you know, is this just because of Sandbox mode? I imagine that in Live mode, PayPal would make sure that the receiver truly exists?

Answer (score 2):

Found this API endpoint today:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/

It seems to do what I wanted, and it at least indirectly test account existence and definitely tests the verified status.

One caveat that I would add for posterity is that in sandbox mode, you may only test against sandbox accounts that you have created for your app.